# Does Flutter Firestore Where clause not support "OR ||" operator

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

StreamBuilder(
stream: _firestore
.collection('MessageData')
**.where( 'RecieverId', isEqualTo: RecieverId)
.where('SenderId', isEqualTo: _auth.currentUser!.uid)
//I Want OR operator here logicaly. How can i do this?
.where( 'RecieverId', isEqualTo: _auth.currentUser!.uid)
.where('SenderId', isEqualTo: RecieverId)**
.snapshots(),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
return ListView(
children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((e) {
return Text(e['Message']);
}).toList(),
);
},
)

**Please go this link to see firestore image.**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `in` operator. This allow to check up to 10 equalities according to documentation.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any